# Angular: Which is the best way of refactoring the code inside ".subscribe()"

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, rxjs, refactoring

Let's say I have a component like this

**The Original Code:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<pre>{{ response | json }}</pre>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  response!: any;

  fetchUsers() {
    this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).subscribe(
      (resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.response = resp;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.response = err;
      },
      () => {
        console.log('Subscription Complete');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

and I have following approaches to refactor the above code...

**Refactor approach 1:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<pre>{{ response | json }}</pre>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  response!: any;

  onSubscribe = (resp: any) => {
    console.log(resp);
    this.response = resp;
  };

  onError = (err: any) => {
    console.error(err);
    this.response = err;
  };

  onCompletion = () => {
    console.log('Subscription Complete');
  };

  fetchUsers() {
    this._http
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .subscribe(this.onSubscribe, this.onError, this.onCompletion);
  }
}
```

**Refactor approach 2:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<pre>{{ response | json }}</pre>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  response!: any;

  onSubscribe(resp: any) {
    console.log(resp);
    this.response = resp;
  }

  onError(err: any) {
    console.error(err);
    this.response = err;
  }

  onCompletion() {
    console.log('Subscription Complete');
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).subscribe(
      (resp) => this.onSubscribe(resp),
      (err) => this.onError(err),
      () => this.onCompletion()
    );
  }
}
```

**Refactor approach 3:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<pre>{{ response | json }}</pre>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  response!: any;

  fetchUsers() {
    this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).subscribe({
      next: (resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.response = resp;
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.response = err;
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('Subscription Complete');
      },
    });
  }
}
```

**Refactor approach 4:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<pre>{{ response | json }}</pre>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  response!: any;

  onSubscribe = (resp: any) => {
    console.log(resp);
    this.response = resp;
  };

  onError = (err: any) => {
    console.error(err);
    this.response = err;
  };

  onCompletion = () => {
    console.log('Subscription Complete');
  };

  fetchUsers() {
    this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).subscribe({
      next: this.onSubscribe,
      error: this.onError,
      complete: this.onCompletion,
    });
  }
}
```

**Refactor approach 5:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<pre>{{ response | json }}</pre>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  response!: any;

  onSubscribe(resp: any) {
    console.log(resp);
    this.response = resp;
  }

  onError(err: any) {
    console.error(err);
    this.response = err;
  }

  onCompletion() {
    console.log('Subscription Complete');
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    this._http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).subscribe({
      next: (resp: any) => this.onSubscribe(resp),
      error: (err: any) => this.onError(err),
      complete: () => this.onCompletion(),
    });
  }
}
```

**Now the question is**

> Considering the performance (in the first place & readability the
> next) - which would be the best choice?
>
> 1. Refactor approach 1?
> 2. Refactor approach 2?
> 3. Refactor approach 3?
> 4. Refactor approach 4?
> 5. Refactor approach 5?
> 6. The Original Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd refactor to a declarative approach

1. Create a service to encapsulate all of the data access.
2. In the service, define a variable (not a method) to manage the Observable returned from the http get.
3. In the component, define a variable (not the constructor or life cycle hook) to manage the Observable returned from the service
4. Use the `async` pipe in the template.

**Example Service:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  users$ = this.http
    .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    .pipe(tap((response) => console.log(response)));

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchUsers() {}
}
```

**Example Component/template**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<pre>{{ users$ | async | json }}</pre>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  errorMessage = '';

  users$ = this.userService.users$.pipe(
    catchError(err => this.errorMessage = err)
  )

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

}
```

See this for more information on this declarative pattern: https://youtu.be/0XPxUa8u-LY

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best approach is the number 4 for the next reasons:

Talking about readability, the way in that you pass three arguments on the subscription (next, error, complete) is actually deprecated for RxJS because function arguments can contribute to hard-to-read-code. [You can read more about it here](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments)

instead, RxJS advises you to use a JS object like an argument where you define the code to the different callbacks

```
({next: () =>{}, error: () =>{}, complete: () =>{})
```

And separating the code into functions can help you make it cleaner to read.

Talking about the performance if you pass an argument like a JS object to the subscription RxJS passes an empty function to one of the callbacks instead of you doing it on your own.